# Modding my laptop, is 5v to 12v step up module safe for motherboard?

Tags: motherboard

i'm not a tech savvy, nor an electrician, barely know anything about pcb and such, thus having this question, it'll probably noob question, but please stick with me, and also i'm not sure if i post this into the correct forum

so i have old MSi GE60, its already +-6 years, monitor breaking up and what not, but the internal hardware still very much working great

my plan is to gut all the hardware and convert the laptop into a family media center, i already planned everything , the custom case etc, the problem is, i want to put another fan on the case, and take the power for the fan directly from the mobo

since MSi GE60 have unused PCie SSD, i'll buy the PCie to USB module, BUT, since almost all fan in market is powered with 12v , i also planning to buy the 5v to 12v step up module to put on the PCie to USB module

my problem is, i don't know if such setup is safe for the laptop motherboard, anyone can enlighten me?

thank you in advance

note : 
i already post the question notebookreview forum, but theres no conclusive answer (with reasons) as of yet

the step up module i'm speak of : https://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/Universal-2-1x5-5-mm-Micro-USB-Cable-DC-5V-to-12V-Step-up-Boost-Line/333670_32679700740.html

MSi GE60 mobo : https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1qgTqMVXXXXcXXXXXq6xXFXXXd/MS-16GA1-For-MSI-GE60-Laptop-Motherboard-Mainboard-100-Tested-fully-work.jpg

Comment: There are loads of 5V fans on the market, that would make far more sense, better use of power and create less heat than using a step-up converter. Your power is already starting at battery voltage and being stepped down to 5V and wasting power and creating heat in the process.

Comment: true, but i'm looking for ready/available fan supply in my country, which is mostly 12v, i can buy 5v 80mm 5v fan from aliexpress or something like that, but its just take quite a while to come, mostly 2 months

Comment: It would be much safer to borrow some current from the power plug (it would be around 19V, so you'll have to step down to 12V).

Comment: I tend to agree with the other commenters that the tactic you're asking about is probably not the best solution to your actual problem. However, I still think the question itself is valid and pretty well-formulated, so you got my +1.

Comment: yeah, his solution probably the best, but i also probably need to take a bit of guide before doing it later lol, google might cover that tho
and thanks for the +1, quite lot of people -1 it , even tho i don't know wheres the problem

Comment: @laptop no it should have stayed open,  modding things are explicitly on topic

Comment: @Passerby, yep your right again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on where you are planning to draw current from. Likely, your laptop power supply is not 5V but something like 19V, so 5V line on the PCB is fed from DC-DC step-down converter mounted on PCB. It's not safe, nor is it convenient to feed from that line. And it's especially non-efficient to connect a step-up converter to the line fed from a step-down because each conversion has about 80% to 90% efficiency and the whole chain will be losing about half the power.
Much safer way would be to take 19V straight from the power connector and use a step-down converter to get 12V you need.

Comment: thanks for the awesome reply, that clear lot of confussion on my part

Comment: Convenient no, but safe? Probably if they don't do anything stupid.

Comment: @Passerby I mean not safe for a computer. Of course it's safe for OP.

Comment: On any given computer, I assume 1 to 2 Amps can be pulled safely from the 5v rail.  That's what usb does.